# Any disadvantages or security issues for having website and databases on separate servers?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, amazon-ec2, odoo, infrastructure

We're about to dive into Odoo (OpenERP). We're planning on using Amazon EC2 for the actual installation, and put the postgreSQL database server on Amazon RDS. (like this guide http://toolkt.com/site/install-openerp-server-and-postgresql-on-separate-servers/ )

If the RDS is only allowed to talk to the EC2 server, does this mitigate any security issues compared to a regular Odoo installation (where database and front facing webserver are on the same machine)? Is this an advisable setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input data in your post is very vague to give you exact answer, but you may consider the following:

1. `RDS` can talk to `EC2` or any other clients and application servers. Connection only depends on your configuration. You can configure **[VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/)** and configure/restrict access to your database and application servers there.
2. Depending on the size of your system (in terms of I/O, number of users , etc), of course you may want to configure separate database instance and application servers. At scale this separation is important.

Comment: I think this answer captures the gist of what I would have said, except that it doesn't quite go far enough -- separating the database and the web app on different servers is the *preferred* solution, for performance, scalability, security, and essentially any reason you can come up with, other than cost.  I would go so far as to say it is the "most correct" approach, and yes, use VPC, not EC2-Classic.  With RDS, there is no "backdoor" to the data achievable by directly accessing the server that RDS runs on, because the server itself is not accessible -- only the database server is accessible.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I agree

Comment: Scale is pretty small. We're only looking at around 4-5 users putting in accounting data at any one time, and a small number of customers accessing the website portal at any one time.
I'll take a look at VPC

Answer (score 0):

In short, Nither any Disadvantage nor any security issues.

In Detail Odoo with AWS EC2,

## We "SnippetBucket.com" Team had implemeneted already RDS and better know odoo security.

- RDS is bit very expensive.
- RDS make private instead of public in AWS
  make complete secured.

As well AWS Security helps to make extra protection with inbound and outbound ports. Totally Safe.

Note: AWS **"RDS Aurora-Postgresql"** is 4X faster than official postgresql. AWS RDS support specific versions by AWS.